# How can I pass a vector as argument of a SQL function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I frequently use SQL functions having scalars as arguments.

However, this time I want to pass a vector, a series of floats of non-fixed length that should be evaluated by the function to then throw a scalar.

Do you know how I can pass a vector into the SQL function?

Comment: do you have any example of what you want as an output?

Comment: You can use a table-valued parameter. Aim for an inline table-valued function, because a scalar function has terrible performance. For more complicated scenarios where you really need speed (as you'd often do with floating point) use CLR functions or SQL Server's options for integrating with R.

Comment: As Jeroen pointed out, you can use table-valued parameters ([read details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)), you might even check the [memory optimized table parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/memory-optimized-table-variables?view=sql-server-2014). One more idea was a container type such as XML or JSON.